# Race condition on jQuery animate / toggle / hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I am finding intermittent issues with a hover effect leaving one element in the opposite toggled state of all the others, but it is not happening each time.

It seems to depend on which element in a grid of divs is mouseenter/mouseleave'd first:

```
  $('#portfolio li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.info').stop(false, false).animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
            opacity: 'toggle'
        }, 300, 'linear');
  });
```

The grid can be [seen here](http://prolink-consulting.com/jobs/) in the body of the page, with the "stickyness" seen depending on the timing that the first 1 or 2 divs are mouseentered into.

Different combinations of (*true,true*) (*true, false*) etc. do not stop this first hovered div from becoming sticky (but not every time).

As seen in the image below, 2 divs are being hovered simultaneously, which should never occur:

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time replicating this. Can you give a specific instance where this issue occurs without fail? Or is this (seemingly) completely random?

Comment: If positioning the cursor within the middle of the gird, reloading the page and moving the mouse around the grid whilst the page is loading it seems easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

The solution (directed towards by a friend), was to replace the single hover event and `toggle` parameter with unique `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, with this being the final code solution:

```
  $('#portfolio li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.info').not(":animated").stop(true, true).animate({
            height: ['show', 'swing'],
            opacity: '1'
        }, 300, 'linear');
  });

  $('#portfolio li').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.info').stop(false, true).animate({
            height: ['hide', 'swing'],
            opacity: '0'
        }, 300, 'linear');
  });
```